# Powershell registry - Search whole key/subkey

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-ise

I want to be able to search the using a wildcard for a set of servers that are being retired.  The search will be something like this: *server*  I need to search the following areas:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\<userprofile>\Printers\Connections
```

in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\Servers`

For the first key I basically need to search everything under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\`  since there can be multiple users that logged on to a machine.

```
$strkeyone = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Providers\\Client Side Rendering Print Provider'
```

Instead of searching for a specific value like below, how can I search the whole Client Side Rendering Print Provider?

```
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\machines.csv' | % {
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",
           $_.machinename)
  $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($strkeyname)
  $value = $key.GetValue('blah')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used PDQ Inventory from admin arsenal.They have tools that I believe would make this so much easier. Along with Inventory management you can scan machines in so many ways including the registry. This video is about 3 or 4 versions back.

https://youtu.be/SLCSMrqrf-Y